# echoing a specific part of an array in XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

I'm building some error management into my script and need some advice on how to get it functioning correctly.

I'm confused as how to actually output my messages into the result function. My script starts with an IF statement and if there's a problem, it will choose one of the errors from my error function. (How would I specifically choose which error?)

So to start with I have:

```
if ($_GET)
{

    // run function

} else {

    return $this->error();

}
```

Now the error function:

```
private function error($errnum=1000) {
$data = array(
  'error' => array(
    '1000' => 'Required parameter is missing',
    '1100' => 'Parameter not recognized',
    '2000' => 'Currency type not recognized',
    '2100' => 'Currency amount must be to 2 decimal places',
    '3000' => 'Service currently unavailable',
    '3100' => 'Error in service'
  )
);  
$this->result($data);
}
```

And finally the result function:

```
private function result($data=array(),$type='XML') {
    switch(strtolower($type)) {     
        case 'xml':

            header("Content-type: text/html"); // Set header type to XML
            $output = new SimpleXMLElement('<conv/>'); // Convert our php array to simpleXML
            array_walk_recursive($data, array ($output, 'addChild'));
            echo $output->asXML();

        break;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand .. you can choose the error however you want to.

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to do this. (I'm very new to PHP so everything up there is confusing to me)

Comment: If you wanted to use error 1100, you could call `$this->error(1100);`

Comment: I've tried this but it's not doing anything. I think there's a mistake somewhere in one of my functions

Comment: You never actually use the `errnum` parameter anywhere.

Comment: hmm so how can I add that? (Apologies, I'm very new to this)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6435/discussion-between-tctc91-and-tandu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was this line causing the issue:

$this->result($data);

I had to change the data var into an array.